# What IDE (Eclipse or Aptana) and What tools i need to develop a JSP Project

Tags: eclipse, jsp, aptana, eclipse-wtp

I need to create a web based project where I will use java codes to do the back-end processing and database connections. So I need to write my code in JSP. I already installed tomcat.

But in Aptana i do not get the option "New Dynamic Web Project". Which i have created JSP projects previously. Any one knows how to add it or what toold i need to install?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a fan of Aptana; in my experience it's a bloated tool that tries to do too much and does nothing particularly well. I would just get the **Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers** package from http://www.eclipse/downloads and use that.